# fast way for string comparison

Tags: c++, string, string-comparison

I have a simple question but it makes me confused.

I have two strings, and I want to count how many different characters between the two. The strings are sorted, equal length. Do not split the strings.

For example

```
input:  abc, bcd
output: 2, because a and d are different characters

input:  abce, bccd
output: 4, because a, c, d and e are different.
```

I know I can do it in O(N^2), but how can I solve it in O(N) for these sorted strings?

Only need the number of different characters, no need to indicate which number.

Comment: Are both only alphanumeric chars? So you can make histogram of those chars (histograms for both strings separately). Then just compare histogram columns of zero elements. (O(n) + O(n) + O(very small m*m))

Comment: _"I know I can do it in O(N2)"_ How are you doing so? You probably can't do it (sorted strings or not), to catch all of the differences.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ "How are you doing so?" By using fingers.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow You do jokes now instead of providing answers for LQ questions? Well, you seem to improve now.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Huh? [Why not something like this?](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ce3d25a622c222d0)

Comment: @dyp It outputs 3 not 4, and doesn't specify why?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Yes, sorry, I forgot the final loops: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ce3d25a622c222d0

Comment: @dyp Better, but not complete yet.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ What is missing?

Comment: @dyp _"What is missing?"_ The _because a, c, d and e are different._ part.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ D'oh, I thought this was a comment rather than a part of the actual output.

Comment: @dyp How did you miss that actually from the _requirements_ specified in the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was originally thinking that you needed a fairly complicated algorithm, like [Smith-Waterman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith%E2%80%93Waterman_algorithm) for example. But the restrictions on your input makes it fairly easy to implement this in `O(m + n)`, where `m` is the length of the first string, and `n` is  the length of the second string.

We can use a builtin algorithm to calculate the number of characters that are in common, and then we can use that information to produce the number you are looking for:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::string m = "abce";
    std::string n = "bccd";
    std::string result;

    std::set_intersection(
            m.begin(), m.end(),
            n.begin(), n.end(),
            std::back_inserter(result));

    std::cout << m.size() + n.size() - 2 * result.size() << "\n";
}
```

In this particular case, it outputs `4`, as you wanted.

Comment: If you only need the number, but not the different characters, you can write an algorithm that doesn't need memory allocations: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/909d1f4747991164

Comment: @dyp: Absolutely. We could also write an output iterator that just counts how many times it was incremented. But it is pretty nice to solve these problems in 2 lines of code.

Answer (score 1):

After seeing how simple the answer really is, thanks to @Bill Lynch , my solution may be too complex! Anyways, its a simple counting-difference.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>

int main() {
    std::array<int,26> str1 = {};
    std::array<int,26> str2 = {};

    std::string s1("abce");
    std::string s2("bccd");


    for(char c : s1)
        ++str1[c-'a'];
    for(char c : s2)
        ++str2[c-'a'];

    int index = 0;

    std::cout << std::count_if(str1.begin(),str1.end(),[&](int x)
    {
        return x != str2[index++];
    });
}
```

Its `O(n+m)`, unless I've made a mistake in the analysis.

Comment: Wow, good point. How in the world could I let that go. Thanks!

Comment: I did notice that, which is why I did the `str1.fill(0)` and `str2.fill(0)` calls, but yes, the braced initializer is much cleaner. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve O(n) using [dynamic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming). i.e. use an integer `d` for storing difference.

```
Algo:
move from lower index to higher index of both array.  
if a[i] not equal b[j]:
           increase d by 2
           move the index of smaller array and check again.
if a[i] is equal to b[j] : 
           decrease d by 1
           move both index
repeat this until reach the end of array
```

Answer (score -1):

O(2n) and O(n) are exactly the same thing, since the "O" indicates the asymptotic behavior for the cost of your method.

*Update*: I just noticed you meant O(n^2) with your O(N2).

If you need to do that comparison, you'll always have O(n^2) as your cost, since you have to:

1) **Loop** for every character of your words, and this is *O(n)*

2) **Compare** the current character in each word, and you'll have to use a temporary list that contains the characters you have already checked. So, this is another nested O(n).

So, O(n) * O(n) = **O(n^2)**.

*Note*: you can always ignore a numeric coefficient inside your O expression, as it doesn't matter.

Comment: _"O(2n)"_ The OP probably meant _O(n^2)_.

Comment: @Sergio0694: As seen in the comments and in my answer, you can solve this problem in fewer than `O(n^2)` comparisons.